# How to populate an UICollectionView cell with images from Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm building an app that needs an image slideshow as the background of the welcome controller. My plan is to import images into a folder in Firebase Storage, set a Service function to download the folder's images and append to a model, then populate the controller's collection view cell with the images. Am I on the correct path to do an image slideshow? Thanks.

// BackgroundImage Model

```
struct BackgroundImage {
    
    let backgroundImageUrl: String
    
    init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.backgroundImageUrl = dictionary["backgroundImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    
}
```

// Service

```
struct BgImgs {
    let backgroundImage: UIImage
}

static func fetchBackgroundImages(bgImgs: BgImgs, completion: @escaping([BackgroundImage]) -> Void) {
        
        var backgroundImages = [BackgroundImage]()
        
        guard let imageData = bgImgs.backgroundImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = STORAGE_REF.reference(withPath: "/background_images/\(filename)")
        
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (meta, error) in
            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let backgroundImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                
                let values = ["backgroundImageUrl" : backgroundImageUrl]
                let bgImages = BackgroundImage(dictionary: values)
                backgroundImages.append(bgImages)
                completion(backgroundImages)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

// WelcomeController

```
private var backgroundImages = [BackgroundImage]()

func fetchBackgroundImages() {
        Service.fetchBackgroundImages(bgImgs: backgroundImages) { backgroundImages in
            self.backgroundImages = backgroundImages
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking here as the code in the question doesn't seem to match the question. Typically, image urls would be stored in Firestore or the Real Time Database. You would read those in, iterate over each one and retrieve the image from storage. I am not seeing where those images are being stored in `putData` nor being read in. Perhaps I am overlooking something - can you clarify what the question is and then add the associated code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reload the `UICollectionView` after `fetchBackgroundImages` fetch is done.

```
func fetchBackgroundImages() {
        Service.fetchBackgroundImages(bgImgs: backgroundImages) { backgroundImages in
            self.backgroundImages = backgroundImages
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```